# bus error and "kernal protection error" python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, macos

I am working on a project with Python and a wx Simple Wizard.  Within my wizard, when moving to the fourth and final page, it kicks off a method called `beginCreateInstallation()`.  This in turn creates a separate thread for a file copy (along with a few other minor thins) but also keeps the Wizard thread alive.

Here is the method:

```
def beginCreateInstallation(self, parent):
    '''Install the files to the drive. We need to do this
    in a thread so the gui continues to update.
    '''
    
    #Disable the buttons so they can't move.
    wx.FindWindowById(wx.ID_BACKWARD).Disable()
    wx.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD).Disable()
    
    #Start the thread
    #from installer import createInstall 
    createInstallThread = threading.Thread(target=self.Installer.createInstall, args=[parent, self.selectedDrive])
    createInstallThread.setDaemon(True)
    try: createInstallThread.start()
    except: print "Boom goes the dynamite."
```

The thread that gets run is `Installer.createInstall`.  At the end of `createInstall()`, it calls a single method back in the original class called `installComplete()`.

So, at the end of the thread, it calls a method of the parent, and then should die.

This works fine on Windows, but on OSX I get a bus error and "kernal protection error".

If I kill the thread, and add the follow lines to the bottom of `beginCreateInstall()` I add these lines:

```
        createInstallThread.join()
        self.installComplete()
```

Which in turn kills the threading and freezes the wizard, but I don't get the bus error.

Any help getting this threading working? Where I can get threading to work on OSX?

Comment: Are you using the `threading` module?